# Angular material group dropdown - How to add group name to text box

Tags: angular-material2

I have a material group dropdown designed just like the official documentation ([here](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#creating-groups-of-options)).

Question is : How can I display the selected item text along with group name.

ie; If I select Bulbasaur from 'Grass' group, as in the image, it should show 'Grass - Bulbasaur' instead of just 'Bulbasaur'. Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

**Update**: I have found a work around. Anyone fiddling around with the same issue can do this css hack in the mean time,

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-select placeholder="Pokemon" [formControl]="pokemonControl">
  <mat-option>-- None --</mat-option>
   <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of pokemonGroups" [label]="group.name"
              [disabled]="group.disabled">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let pokemon of group.pokemon" [value]="pokemon.value">
     <span style=display:none">{{group.name}} -</span>{{ pokemon.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-optgroup>
 </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the proper way to do this is to set **"custom trigger text"**:

[See the examples for the MatSelect instead of the overview](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples)

So you would do something like this:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Pokemon" [formControl]="pokemonControl">
    <mat-select-trigger *ngIf="pokemonControl.value; let pokemon">
      {{ pokemon.parentViewValue }} : {{ pokemon.viewValue }}
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option>-- None --</mat-option>
    <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of pokemonGroups" [label]="group.name"
                  [disabled]="group.disabled">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let pokemon of group.pokemon" [value]="pokemon">
        {{pokemon.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-optgroup>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Take note of two things:

1. Obviously the **mat-select-trigger** tag... I am using the full pokemon model, you will need to add either a reference to the parent group or, like I have done, add the parent view value in each pokemon. You can do either when you actually construct the model
2. My **[value]** for the **mat-option** tag is pokemon instead of pokemon.value as I need the full model